# Error using Delimiters in mySql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to run this procedure.

```
USE dbsample
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateBooks (IN book_id VARCHAR(20), IN units INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE books
SET quantity = quantity – units
WHERE isbn = book_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

though i have checked at various places an syntax seems right to me. BUT i am getting the following error

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
>   CREATE PROCEDURE updateBooks (IN book_id VARCHAR(20), IN units INT)' at line 2
>   Line 1, column 1
>
> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END //
>   DELIMITER' at line 1
>   Line 8, column 1

Any help would be great. ANd i am using mySQL version 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **have to** terminate `USE` statement with a delimiter (in your case it is a semicolon).

```
USE dbsample;
            ^
```

Another problem is that you're using dash (`–`) instead of minus character (`-`) in

```
... SET quantity = quantity – units
                            ^
```

---

**UPDATE:** Now since `UPDATE` is the only statement in your procedure you don't have to use `BEGIN ... END` block and change `DELIMITER`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE updateBooks(IN book_id VARCHAR(20), IN units INT)
UPDATE books
   SET quantity = quantity - units
 WHERE isbn = book_id;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a70bb)** demo

Comment: thanks that fixed it, but i am having this another error

Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– units
WHERE isbn = book_id;
END' at line 4

Comment: i was thinking may be using underscore is not correct.. but i do wnat to make sure before changing the name to something else...

Comment: The problem is that you're using dash instead of minus character. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo.