# PDO Exception for MySQL Create Function :: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to create mysql function through PDO execute statement, but it is giving below error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'DELIMITER $$
>       CREATE FUNCTION `diff_func` (`DATE_STR` VARCHAR(255),`COMP_DATE`' at line 1

Code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `diff_func` (`DATE_STR` VARCHAR(255),`COMP_DATE` DATETIME,`AGO` INT(11)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE COMPARE_WITH DATETIME DEFAULT UTC_TIMESTAMP;
        DECLARE AGO_STRING VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE DIFF_STRING VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE DIFFERENCE_VAL VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE RETURN_STRING VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;

        SET RETURN_STRING = '';
        RETURN RETURN_STRING;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278375/error-using-delimiters-in-mysql

Comment: Sorry.. I've tried with delimiter(//) and without delimiter and but it is unable to process.

Comment: ***@SimhachalamGulla***: How are you executing this SQL script? Using MySQL Client or PHP ?

Comment: through PHP..
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Don't use 'Delimiter' while using PHP.

Comment: It is working now without delimiter.. thanks a lot Ravinder and Sumurai :)